# What is the correct german translation of the word "housing" for each sentence of these sentences?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, sentence-structure, scientific-language

What is the correct german translation of the word "housing" for each sentence of these sentences?

1. **Master of Science in Housing:**

a- Master of Science im Wohnungswesen

or

b- Master of Science im Wohnungsbau

2. **Research project in Housing:**

a- Forschungsprojekt in Wohnungswesen

b- Forschungsprojekt in Wohnungsbau

3. **Planning and housing development**

a- Planung und Wohnungsbauentwicklung

b- Planung und Wohnsiedlung

c- Planung und Wohnbauentwicklung

4. **Housing research method**

a- Wohnbauforschungsmethode

b- Methode der Wohnbauforschung

c- Wohnungsbauforschungsmethode

5. **Housing management and finance**

a- Wohnungsmanagement und Finanzierung

b- Wohnungsbaumanagement

6. **Housing design**

a- Wohnbaugestaltung

b- Wohnraumgestaltung

c- Wohnungsplanung

7. **Socio-economic aspects of Housing**

a- Sozioökonomische Aspekte des Wohnungsbaus

8. **Law and Housing**

a- Recht und Wohnungswesen

b- Recht und Wohnungsbau

Please give me the correct answer if one of these sentences is wrong!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you modify the preposition. The following "im" is short for "in dem".

> Master of Science **im** Wohnungswesen, Wohnungsbau, …

Secondly, which word you should use depends on the concrete case.

"Wohnungswesen" ist the broadest term.

"Wohnungsbau" refers only to construction and what's narrowly connected to construction.

"Wohnsiedlung" refers to a single place, one housing complex. This is not what you want to convey with "Planung und Wohnsiedlung", I assume.

"Wohnung" as in "Wohnungsmanagement" would most commonly be understood as the management of one or several apartments on an individual level, for example what a janitor/caretaker does.

In "Wohnraum", "Raum" can have to meanings: space or a room. "Wohn-" here means that its purpose is accommodation. "Gestaltung" again is very broad and could mean the decorating of one room, or the way that a city plans its buildings for housing.

Comment: Thank you so much!